# Pick Color with JComboBox Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox where I want for user to select color. JComboBox is displaying just the colors, without any text. I've come up with this solution. Please advise me if this is good or it should be avoided and why. I am new to Swing and Java in general so please be patient :)

```
public class ToolBar{
    private MainFrame mainFrame;

    public ToolBar (MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    public JPanel getToolBar(){

        JPanel toolbarPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,2,2));
        toolbarPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(mainFrame.getScreenWidth(),60));
        toolbarPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));

        JButton fillButton = new JButton("Fill: ");
        fillButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,20));
        //fillButton.setBackground(Color.red);
        toolbarPanel.add(fillButton);

        String[] test = {" ", " " , " " , " " , " " , " "};
        JComboBox colorBox = new JComboBox(test);
        colorBox.setMaximumRowCount(5);
        colorBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
        colorBox.setRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
        toolbarPanel.add(colorBox);

        return toolbarPanel;
    }
    class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {  
         public MyCellRenderer() {  
             setOpaque(true);  
         }  
         public Component getListCellRendererComponent(  
             JList list,  
             Object value,  
             int index,  
             boolean isSelected,  
             boolean cellHasFocus)  
         {  
             setText(value.toString()); 
             switch (index) {
                case 0:  setBackground(Color.white);
                break;
                case 1:  setBackground(Color.red);
                break;
                case 2:  setBackground(Color.blue);
                break;
                case 3:  setBackground(Color.yellow);
                break;
                case 4:  setBackground(Color.green);
                break;
                case 5:  setBackground(Color.gray);
                break;
             }
             return this;  
         }  
    }
}
```

This works ok. It is displaying empty selection elements in JComboBox with different colors. Problem is that when user selects color, color of selection in JComboBox does not change. Which lines of code should I add and where so that when user selects the color from a list that color is displayed in JComboBox field?

I tried some solutions but result was that when user picks color selection in JComboBox always changes to gray...

I've looked through several similar questions but I just can't figure out which part of code is dealing with changing of color of JComboBox when the selection has been done...

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: I used CODE button to mark the code in my question... I will try with {} next time ;) Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, should work. You have to override setBackground... because, internal mechanism  uses default colors from current Look&Feel:

```
Color[] colors={Color.white,Color.red,Color.blue,Color.green};
JComboBox colorBox = new JComboBox(colors);
colorBox.setMaximumRowCount(5);
colorBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
colorBox.setRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```

And ListCellRender:

```
class MyCellRenderer extends JButton implements ListCellRenderer {  
     public MyCellRenderer() {  
         setOpaque(true); 

     }
     boolean b=false;
    @Override
    public void setBackground(Color bg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(!b)
         {
             return;
         }

        super.setBackground(bg);
    }
     public Component getListCellRendererComponent(  
         JList list,  
         Object value,  
         int index,  

         boolean isSelected,  
         boolean cellHasFocus)  
     {  

         b=true;
         setText(" ");           
         setBackground((Color)value);        
         b=false;
         return this;  
     }  
}
```

Comment: Cheers m8! Much appreciated!
I just changed `setText(" ");` to `setText("");`and added `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));` line to getListCellRendererComponent method to fully achieve what I was aiming for. Would vote you up but I need 15 reputation :) Thanks again m8!

Answer (score 2):

ComboBox uses equals and all your strings are equal.
Define color names

```
String[] test = {"red", "green" , "blue" ...};
```

But in the renderer call `setText(" ");`

Comment: I've changed code as you have instructed to:

`toolbarPanel.add(fillButton);
  
  String[] test = {"white", "red" , "blue" , "yellow" , "green" , "gray"};
  JComboBox colorBox = new JComboBox(test);`

and in renderer to:

`setText(" ");
          switch (index) {
             case 0:  setBackground(Color.white);
             break;`

but still when I make the selection gray color is displayed in JComboBox, regardless of the color I have selected...

Thank you for your time m8! Appreciated!

Comment: I'd be use safe Color colors[] = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW};

Comment: @mKorbel agree that colors are better:)

Comment: Instead of using switch(index) process value and set the color from the value.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, cheers! :) Alhugone's code is doing exactly what i was aiming for. Gonna experiment these days a little with ListCellRenderers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a case for index == -1 and set the background color of the cell renderer to the most recent user selection.