# How can i display colors in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, colors, jcombobox

The main idea is, that the Combo box should show colors in the selection area instead of the normal String.
This is the code i've made so far.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Colors extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JComboBox combo;
private JPanel panel;
private final Color[] content = {Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.black,   
                                 Color.yellow};

public Colors() {
    super("Colors");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(500, 150);
    setSize(250, 100);
    setResizable(false);
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel = new JPanel();
    c.add(panel);
    getCombo();
}

private void getCombo() {

    combo = new JComboBox(content);
    combo.setSelectedIndex(4);
    combo.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(combo);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == combo) {
        int choose = combo.getSelectedIndex();
        if (choose == 0) {
            panel.setBackground(content[0]);
        } else if (choose == 1) {
            panel.setBackground(content[1]);
        } else if (choose == 2) {
            panel.setBackground(content[2]);
        } else if (choose == 3) {
            panel.setBackground(content[3]);
        } else if (choose == 4) {
            panel.setBackground(content[4]);
        } else if (choose == 5) {
            panel.setBackground(content[5]);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Colors run = new Colors();
    run.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

This just show awt reference and the GBR number, I want the colors to be shown in the Combo box

Comment: please share some code

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830098/pick-color-with-jcombobox-java-swing

Comment: Take a look at [How to use combo boxes, providing a custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)